# How can I find host which has large and least free memory available from N given hosts?

Tags: bash

I want to find which host has greatest free memory available and least free memory available from N number of array hosts and migrate the VM from least free memory host to greatest memory host. Currently, my script is working for only three hosts but I need scripts for dynamic number of hosts. Can you any one please help me on the script logic? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
array_host=($(xe host-list params=uuid | cut -c 17-))
#Loop throguh each xen server node

for i in ${array_host[@]};

do
   host_name+=($(xe host-list params=name-label uuid=$i| cut -c 23-))

   free_mem1=$(xe host-data-source-query data-source=memory_free_kib uuid=$i)

   mem_int=( ${free_mem1/\.*} )

   mem_mb=$(($mem_int/1024))

   free_mem+=( $mem_mb )

   total_mem+=($(xe host-data-source-query data-source=memory_total_kib uuid=$i))

   load_avg+=($(xe host-data-source-query data-source=loadavg uuid=$i))

   cpu_avg+=($(xe host-data-source-query data-source=cpu_avg uuid=$i))

   no_vms+=$(xe vm-list resident-on=$i | grep -c running)

done


if (( ${free_mem[2]} < ${free_mem[1]} && ${free_mem[2]} < ${free_mem[0]} )); 
then

vm_list=($(xe vm-list params=uuid is-control-domain=false resident-on=${array_host[2]} | cut -c 17-))

for vm in ${vm_list[@]};

do
   if (( ${free_mem[1]} <  ${free_mem[0]} )); then

      xe vm-migrate uuid=${vm_list[0]} host-uuid=${array_host[0]} --live

      echo ${vm_list[0]} has been migrated from xen-node2 to xen-node3
   else

      xe vm-migrate uuid=${vm_list[0]} host-uuid=${array_host[1]} --live

      echo ${vm_list[0]} has been migrated from xen-node2 to xen-node1
fi

done

fi

if (( ${free_mem[1]} < ${free_mem[2]} && ${free_mem[1]} < ${free_mem[0]} )); 
then


vm_list=($(xe vm-list params=uuid is-control-domain=false resident-on=${array_host[1]} | cut -c 17-))

for vm in ${vm_list[@]};

do

   if (( ${free_mem[2]} <  ${free_mem[0]} )); then

      xe vm-migrate uuid=${vm_list[0]} host-uuid=${array_host[0]} --live

      echo ${vm_list[0]} has been migrated from xen-node1 to xen-node3

   else

      vm_list=($(xe vm-list params=uuid is-control-domain=false resident-on=${array_host[1]} | cut -c 17-))

      xe vm-migrate uuid=${vm_list[0]} host-uuid=${array_host[2]} --live

      echo ${vm_list[0]} has been migrated from xen-node1 to xen-node2
 fi

done

fi



if (( ${free_mem[0]} < ${free_mem[1]} && ${free_mem[0]} < ${free_mem[2]} )); 
then

vm_list=($(xe vm-list params=uuid is-control-domain=false resident-on=${array_host[0]} | cut -c 17-))

for vm in {vm_list[@]};

do
   if (( ${free_mem[1]} <  ${free_mem[2]} )); then

      xe vm-migrate uuid=${vm_list[0]} host-uuid=${array_host[2]} --live

      echo ${vm_list[0]} has been migrated from xen-node3 to xen-node2
   else

      xe vm-migrate uuid=${vm_list[0]} host-uuid=${array_host[1]} --live

      echo ${vm_list[0]} has been migrated from xen-node3 to xen-node1
fi

done

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tmp_min_memory`, `tmp_min_host`, `tmp_max_memory`, `tmp_max_host` temporary variables. Put data about hosts in array, put first element data in `tmp_min_memory`, `tmp_min_host`, `tmp_max_memory` and `tmp_max_host`. Loop through array. When you find a host that has less memory available then `tmp_min_memory`, update `tmp_min_memory` and `tmp_min_host`. Similarly, each time you encounter host with more memory than `tmp_max_memory`, update `tmp_max_memory` and `tmp_max_host`. At the end perform same operations as you did.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! It seems difficult for me to do that. It would be great if sample script is available. Thanks.

Comment: I will provide when I get back to office, no worries ;) expect in an hour or two, i hope you dont mind

Comment: No problem ! Thanks. :)

Comment: Oh, another user already provided the implementation in his answer :)

Answer (score 0):

seems there are 6 arrays in respective order `host_name free_mem total_mem load_avg cpu_avg no_vms`.

running through array indexes, an example to have hosts with least and greatest free memory

```
tmp_min_free_mem=9999999999999
tmp_max_free_mem=0

for ((i=0;i<${#host_name[@]};i+=1)); do

    if ((free_mem[i]<tmp_min_free_mem)); then

        tmp_min_free_mem=${free_mem[i]}
        tmp_min_free_mem_host=${host_name[i]}

    fi


    if ((free_mem[i]>tmp_max_free_mem)); then

        tmp_max_free_mem=${free_mem[i]}
        tmp_max_free_mem_host=${host_name[i]}

    fi


done

echo "$tmp_min_free_mem_host $tmp_min_free_mem"
echo "$tmp_max_free_mem_host $tmp_max_free_mem"
```

EDIT: after comments the first answer shows how to keep the min and max, to sort the whole table

```
# sort to a file
for ((i=0;i<${#host_name[@]};i+=1)); do
    echo "$i,${host_name[i]},${free_mem[i]}"
done | sort -t, -nk3 > sorted.txt

# loop read the file to feed new arrays
new_hosts=()
new_freemem=()
while IFS=, read index host freemem; do
    new_hosts+=("$host")
    new_freemem+=("$freemem")        
done < sorted.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am just confused, will  tmp_max_free_mem_host=${host_name[i-1]} will return host which has second max memory?

Comment: no only the hosts min and max are memorized in tmp variables, if the second are needed add new variable to memorize the previous value in the correct if section

Comment: Thanks! Can we include some sorting and get the second max_memory_host from the existing code?

Comment: I think this will do the job: 
tmp__second_max_free_mem=0
tmp_second_max_free_mem=${free_mem[i-1]}
tmp_second_max_free_mem_host=${host_name[i-1]}

Comment: no arrays are not sorted [i-1] has no relation with [i], see update

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.